# Sinusoidal decomposition of signal

Tags: reference-request, fourier-transform, online-resources, reference-works

I have some data of periodic nature. The curve seems to be slightly irregular, and it makes sense to consider it as the sum of two or more different sinusoidals.

I'm asking for a source or tools that will allow me to go from a few data points in an irregular periodic signal, to a series of regular sinusoidal which sum will be the irregular signal. I've considered the Fourier transform, but I wouldn't know how to apply it in a case like this since I have no starting function, but a data points (and not many).

Comment: Use the Discrete Fourier Transform to give you the relative magnitude and phase of frequency components.  Most decent math packages have an FFT function.

Comment: @AndyWalls Packages? So you mean I shouldn't do it by hand, but use a software to perform this computations? Do you think matlab will work?